# SQL select with IF or case

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I'm using SQL server 2008 R2

My SQL statement is like this, for avoiding double data before I inserted:

```
select * from LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP where NOT EXISTS
(
select * from LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL lv
where lv.NOID = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.NOID AND
      lv.CODE_DEST = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.CODE_DEST AND
      lv.CODE_CLIENT = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.CODE_CLIENT AND
      lv.DATE_CLOTURE = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE AND 
      lv.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL =  LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL
)
```

This works fine, but now I want to add a condition:

- When the data `LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE is null`, I don't want to compare.
- When the data `LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL is null`, I don't want to compare

I have changed like this:

```
select * from LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP where NOT EXISTS
(
select * from LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL lv
where lv.NOID = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.NOID AND
      lv.CODE_DEST = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.CODE_DEST AND
      lv.CODE_CLIENT = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.CODE_CLIENT AND
      case LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE 
       when is not null then  lv.DATE_CLOTURE = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE AND 
       end
      case LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL 
       when is not null then   lv.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL =  LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL
       end

)
```

I get a syntax error.

Comment: you have a misplaced `AND` at the end of your first case statement

Comment: Why do you need this condition? Omit both `CASE` fields in the subquery and it should give you the desired result, IMO

Comment: You cannot simply compare values in expression and expect boolean result because there is no boolean data type in Sql Server. You need to enclose the test in another case returning 1 for true and 0 for false.

Answer (score 0):

your CASE statement is incorrect. The correct syntax is `CASE WHEN {condition} THEN {result} END`

```
SELECT * 
FROM LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP where NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM LETTRE_VOIT_FINAL lv
    WHERE lv.NOID = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.NOID 
    AND lv.CODE_DEST = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.CODE_DEST 
    AND lv.CODE_CLIENT = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.CODE_CLIENT 
    AND CASE WHEN LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE IS NOT NULL THEN lv.DATE_CLOTURE = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE END
    AND CASE WHEN LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL IS NOT NULL THEN lv.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL =  LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL END

)
```

You may need to add in an ELSE statement to your CASE of `1 = 1` to avoid another syntax error

Comment: @MahmoudGamal The `AND` at the end of the row messed me up. I re-formatted my answer.

Comment: this syntax lv.DATE_CLOTURE = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE that cause error

Comment: @user1958628 that's an issue in your original query as well then

Comment: i meant this:  AND CASE WHEN LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE IS NOT NULL THEN lv.DATE_CLOTURE = LETTRE_VOIT_TEMP.DATE_CLOTURE END

Comment: at the bottom of my answer it says you may need to add `ELSE 1 = 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can't test for null in this format

```
CASE field WHEN IS NULL THEN x
```

But you can test it like so:

```
CASE WHEN field IS NULL THEN x
```

It should be noted that in SQL Server you can use the following syntax, just not with NULLs

```
CASE field  WHEN condition1 THEN x
            WHEN condition2 THEN y
            ELSE z
END
```